# JavaScript to clear SharePoint Text Filter box on focus

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to clear default value which is "Keyword ...." from a SharePoint text filter box. I put in an alert at line 10 but it doesn't pop-up. Do you any reason why it would not clear the Text Box when a user clicks inside the box to type something.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Clears text box on click or focus    
    var TextBoxID = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_22e9e7dd_3da6_4f0b_bc1c_0874742c6012_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl");     
    TextBoxID.focus(function()
    {
        if(this.value == "Keyword ....")
        {
            alert('test line 10');
            $(this).val("");
        }   
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like for that element?

Comment: I would suggest moving your alert to outside of the if. This could be that the focus isn't happening at all based on what you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an error in your jQuery selector.

Should that have been $('#'+searchID).focus(...)?

If not, I was mislead by the reuse of "searchID" as a local variable and the name of a class on an element.

Comment: Hi, It's Javascript. I want to get away from jQuery as it's been disabling sp.ribbon.js.

Comment: No problem moving away from jQuery. It just appeared that you were using it on line 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

HTML

```
Search Box: <input onclick="clearPlaceholder();" id="ctl00_m_g_22e9e7dd_3da6_4f0b_bc1c_0874742c6012_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl" type="text" name="fname" value="Keyword..."><br>
```

JS

```
function clearPlaceholder(){
    var TextBoxID = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_22e9e7dd_3da6_4f0b_bc1c_0874742c6012_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl");

    TextBoxID.value = "";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5h6H/2/

Comment: Now it's complaining about the $ sign being before the control. This is what I see through Developer Tool Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit in the original post where I took out the $ sign. I dont get any errors. However on focus java does not work either. I put an alert after the focus function and it doesnt pop up either.

Comment: @ShawnTorres You've mentioned you don't want to use Jquery? Yet I still see Jquery in your edited code. Anyways I've updated the above answer for a solution with no jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that solved the issue. I needed to clear the value in the text field when user click inside the text box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Clears text box on click or focus
var TextBoxID = document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_22e9e7dd_3da6_4f0b_bc1c_0815182c6012_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl');
    TextBoxID.onfocus = function(){
        if(this.value == 'Keyword ....')
        {           
            TextBoxID.value="";
        }   
    };  
</script>
```